# Selecting elements to show and hide, traversal issue! (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been trying every combination under the sun of parent()/children()/find() and selector syntax to .show() an element of my webpage that i hid on document ready, but I just can't get it to work! I'd really appreciate it if someone could take a look..

If you go to the portfolio section you can see it live here -> http://holly.im/ .

In any case the html looks something like this:

```
<div id="portfolio">
<h1>Heading</h1>
<div class ="little_column">
  <div class="project"> 
    <a href="#c++_games_engine_construction" class="projlink"> click </a>
  </div>    
</div>
<div id="c++_games_engine_construction" class="big_column">
    <?php include "projects/C++_game_engine_construction.php"; ?>
</div>
</div>
```

And the relevant jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    //hide all the big_columns / 
    // project details within the portfolio page
    $('#portfolio').find('.big_column').hide(); //This seems to be working
});
$(function(){
    $('.project').click(function () {
        var selectedProject =
            $(this).children('a.projlink').attr('href');
        $(this).parent().parent().find(selectedProject).show(); //My most recent attempt, I though maybe i needed to go up the heirachy then back down? But whatever i try it doesn't show.
        return false;
    });
});
```

That's it really, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is with the `+` in the selector. It needs to be escaped because it has special meaning in the Selectors API *(and is invalid for an ID)*.

If you removed the `++` from the `href` and the `id`, it works.

---

Alternately, you can do `.replace(/\+/g, "\\+")`

```
var selectedProject = $(this).children('a.projlink').attr('href').replace(/\+/g, "\\+")
```

---

*Off topic: You don't need two `.ready()` calls, which is what you have, but using different syntax.*

Comment: Cheers I am silly! :) Also I thought maybe window loading and document being ready might be slightly different things (ready to me implies that everything's loaded if you see what i mean.) I should have checked anyway, thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @Holly: Yeah, `window` and `document` loading do have different meaning, but the two syntax you're using both mean `document` ready. The second is just a shorter way of writing the first.

Answer (score 4):

Having the character `+` in the ID of an element causes jQuery to become confused because the `+` character is reserved for the [Next Adjacent Selector](http://api.jquery.com/next-adjacent-Selector/).

If you remove those characters from your code, it works just fine. As was mentioned in one of the comments to this answer, since the href is essentially the ID of the item to be shown, you can select it directly.

HTML

```
<div id="portfolio" class="section">

    <h1>Heading</h1>

    <div class="little_column">
        <div class="project"> <a href="#c_games_engine_construction" class="projlink"> click </a>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="c_games_engine_construction" class="big_column">
        I'm hidden at first!
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //hide all the big_columns / 
    // project details within the portfolio page
    $('#portfolio').find('.big_column').hide(); //This seems to be working
});
$(function () {
    $('.project').click(function () {
        var selectedProject = $(this).children('a.projlink').attr('href');
        $(selectedProject).show(); //My most recent attempt, I though maybe i needed to go up the heirachy then back down? But whatever i try it doesn't show.
        return false;
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jEWa4/3/)

Comment: @Bergi: Are you sure it's still unique after the ID was modified? After all, there is a `c` language too.

Comment: @thesystem I agree with Bergi, the ID would have to be unique. Even if it was written as `c_plus_plus_games_engine_construction`. If the ID is not unique, it will most likely cause quite a few other problems later on.

Comment: @RubenInfante: Yes, but that's my point. There could be another `c_games_engine_construction` ID somewhere on the page. The `plus_plus` is a good idea, but again only if it isn't already used.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, your problem are the `+` characters mistreated by jQuery. So the simple solution is: do not use jQuery - or at least, not for the selector thing. Since every target you have is an id selector, we can easily change it to

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('#portfolio').find('.big_column').hide();

    $('.project').click(function () {
        var selectedProject = $(this).find('a').attr('href'); // a littebit simplified

        var el = document.getElementById(selectedProject.slice(1));
        $(el).show();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: A `+` isn't a valid character for an ID outside of HTML5.

Comment: ...although I don't know if any browsers actually choke on it in their `getElementById()` method.

Comment: @thesystem: Sure, however that shouldn't matter here. The OP should replace it, but I'd guess it wouldn't cause problems in decent browsers even if not delivered as HTML5.